# Python3 one-liner to verify presence of item in dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am looking for a possible one-liner to return the equivalent of

```
'A' in ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

but in a following case:
Suppose I have a dictionary containing lists as values, like:

```
dictionary = {'key1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
              'key2': ['E', 'F'], 
              'key3': ['G', 'H', 'I']}
```

So far the closest I could get was something like:

```
r = {v[0] for k, v in dictionary.items() if 'A' in v}
```

however this returns a set of length 0 or 1 returning the list element for the presence of which I want to check.

I would want to get only True/False regarding if 'A' is present in any of the lists stored in the dictionary values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) built-in function:

```
any('A' in v for v in dictionary.values())
```

`any()` is optimum by itself in terms of returning `True` as soon as encountering a true proposition but if you wanna boost the performance even more you can use `set` objects instead of lists for preserving the values for their membership checking is linear.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to stop iterating over all the dict values even after finding a match, use `itertools.takewhile`

```
import itertools
if list(itertools.takewhile(lambda v: 'J' in v, dictionary.values())):
    # Found
else:
    # Not found
```